# JavaScript - Does execCommand() have a HTML version of <code>?

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor, execcommand

I did my best to make the title make sense.

In essence, I am making a Rich Text Editor (or WYSIWYG). I need to know what to use for JavaScript's execCommand() which can be viewed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). There is not a method that I can see that supports a HTML `<code></code>` blocks just like StackOverflow uses.

Is there an alternative to this that can be used alongside `richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';` that JavaScript uses?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `insertHTML`, not supported in IEs though.